# Check if pandas.DataFrame is equally spaced

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` called `df` with

```py
>>> type(df.index)
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
```

How can I assert that the index is equally spaced? I.e. I am looking for a boolean attribute of `df` or of `df.index` which is

- `True`, if the distance between two consecutive indices is always the same, for example always 10 minutes
- `False`, otherwise.

Is there an in-built attribute or function accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that, assuming the index is numeric:

```
import numpy as np
diff = np.diff(df.index.to_numpy())
Equaly_spaced = np.all(diff==diff[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works for me. I think I still might not use it like this in my code, because someone else who has to read this will not easily understand what's going on.

Comment: @NerdOnTour Comment the hell out of these 2 lines, they sure will